# Loading a subview after clicking a tableCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, subview, didselectrowatindexpath

So I am trying to add in to my current Xcode project a table view which, whenever you click on a cell, whichever one it is, a new subview is added to the window. I will use global variables and the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to pass data on.

As it stands, I have my table view drawn on screen with the correct data inside. What I want to happen is when I click, a new subview is added but i cannot seem to get this to work.

I have tried adding the "addSubview" inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method itself and this did not work and I have tried declaring a separate method that loads a subview called 'loadDetails' then calling it with [self loadDetails] when a cell is selected but it wants an id after the call and I don't know what to pass in.

I have elsewhere in my project used the line:

```
[rightButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(showDetails:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

But I can't see how to adapt this to the tableCell unless I could somehow add a new button over the cell? I really don't know.

If anybody has any other ideas of how to solve this problem, that would be great.

Thanks,

Matt

EDIT:

Problem is now solved, was a really stupid mistake, I forgot to link the view on the xib I was moving to, to the view created programmatically in my header file

Answer (score 0):

try using presentModalViewController to show your view, and then dismiss it from the modalViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

DetailView *detailView = [[DetailView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailView" bundle:nil];

[self presentModalViewController:detailView animated:YES];

}
```